# How can I see what's in internalstorage in android?

Tags: android

Hi I'm writing my first android app using IntelliJ IDEA and was wondering if there any easy way to see the contents of the Internal Storage during development?  I'm writing a Json file and would like to see the contents of the files during a debug session.

Comment: I can't figure out why this was down voted.  Can someone explain so I don't do it again.  Kind of weak that the person that down voted to the question didn't provide any feedback.

Comment: Honestly, I really want to know what's wrong with this question?  One of my goals this year is to become a more active participants on this site.  However, feedback like this is not very encouraging whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Click `DDMS` in `Eclipse` and choose the `File Explorer` tab

Comment: I forgot to mention I"m using IntelliJ IDEA sorry I edited the question now.